# Environment variables in eclipse.ini file

Tags: eclipse, parsing, command-line, variables

Does `eclipse.ini` or eclipse command line support variable parsing such as `$PATH` or `${java.home}`?

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in [FAQ: How do I run Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)

> If available under the eclipse/jre directory, the Eclipse JRE will be used; otherwise the launcher will consult the system path variable. Eclipse will NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

a eclipse command line can use environment variable (like any other command):

```
eclipse -vm $jAVA_HOME/bin
```

would work.

But Eclipse itself (or eclipse.ini) will not use parse directly an environment variable.
A [eclipse.ini like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) only use full paths.

---

Actually, [bug 102239](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102239) is already asking for that kind of feature... since 2005!

> Bug 102239 - [launcher] Environment variable substitution in `<launcher>.ini/eclipse.ini`
>
> It'd be very helpful if the launcher would support the insertion of environment variables in the `<launcher>.ini`.
>   Whatever form might make sense (e.g. `@ENV`, `%ENV%`, `${ENV}`, `${env_var:ENV}`)
>
> e.g. something like

```
-vm
${MYRCPAPP_VM}
-mx${MYRCPAPP_HEAPSIZE}
```

But the answers ask for help on this:

> The launcher is written in C. The code is in the platform-launcher project.
>
> [To] want this on any argument including the vm, vmargs etc, in which case this would need to happen in the native code.

Comment: thanks for the answer; is there a place I can ask for eclipse feature request for this?

Comment: @Java: that would be by opening a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/, but I believe one is already there. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Eclipse bug (feature request), VonC. I have now voted on this bug, and I encourage other readers of this to do the same. (Clik on the link in the answer, register/log in, vote.)

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating the @VonC answer I have created a simple file `eclipse.bat` containing the following simple line:

```
start eclipse.exe -vm %WORK_DIRECTORY%\tools\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe
```

Where I have used a system variable. 
Now, instead of calling directly `eclipse.exe`, I call `eclipse.bat` and this does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to have redefined user name (used e.g. in @author tag) so I have changed the shortcut to eclipse to point to the following:

```
C:\Java\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vmargs -Duser.name=%eclipse_user%
```

Then I have defined user variable eclipse_user which can be set by each user separately. For my needs it's enough.