# How to use environment variables in eclipse.ini?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to use environment variables like `%JAVA_HOME%` within  `eclipse.ini`?

I'd like to include the following without having to hardcode the absolute path to jdk:

```
-vm
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe
```

But that's not working and eclipse complains about missing jdk.

By the way: cmd `echo %JAVA_HOME%` shows the correct path.

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible. There is already a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102239) opened for this.

Also see this question: [eclipse.ini variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2426317)