# Is there a way in Eclipse sts IDE to bulk load many environment variable from file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In IntelliJ i can use the .env plugin that lets you load many env variables from file.

Is there a feature or maybe a plugin available for this in Eclipse?
We need to load many environment variables extracted from our servers to the IDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse.ini variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426317/eclipse-ini-variables)

Comment: Based on that link, and while not related to JAVA_HOME or anything, it  looks like you can likely do it by passing "-D" arguments while starting up eclipse and they then might be available to your application?